# How to make the angular component.ts script run independently via npm run?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, components

I have a `addDataComponent` that is used to add data to database. For the development purpose, I would like to be able to run this ts/component script outside of app. Here is what I tried:

1. `npx ts-node addDataComponent.ts`, but it did not work and the error shows:

```
(node:36051) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

2. add `"type": "module"` in `packages.json` and run `node --loader ts-node/esm addDataComponent.ts`, but it did not work either:

```
(node:50489) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

/Users/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:376
    const err = new ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT(path, fileURLToPath(base));
                ^
Error: ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT /Users/app/src /Users/app/
```

Sorry I don't have a reproducible example, but the format I have in the component is:

```
addDataComponent.html
addDataComponent.ts
addDataComponent.module.ts
```

I am fairly new to angular/typescript and I don't know how to solve the modules issues. What is the best to run a component independently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By meaning running this component, if you mean that you want to run a function inside it, then you can write the function as a service and call it anywhere, anytime.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thanks for answering. I actually would like to run outside of the app. I want to use npm run to run the component.

Comment: Okay. But I do not think an angular component can be run independently.